# Create copy of table on linked server - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a copy of a table in a linked server from a table in my current server:

First, I tried to do it as so:

```
EXEC [server2].[database2].sys.sp_executesql N'drop table if exists [schema2].Table2'

select .*
into [server2].[database2].[schema2].Table2
from [database1].[schema1].Table1
```

Now, from this I get '(...) contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.'

I then tried this:

```
insert into [server2].[database2].[schema2].Table2
select *
from [database1].[schema1].Table1
```

And It says that [server2].[database2].[schema2].Table2 does not exist.

Then I tried:

```
select * into ##Table3
from [database1].[schema1].Table1

EXEC [server2].[database2].sys.sp_executesql N'select * into [schema2].Table2 
    from ##Table1'
```

And still get 'Invalid object name '##Table1'.

What can I do to achieve this?
Thank you,

Comment: You *can't* use `SELECT...INTO` on a remote database; this is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments). As the the `INSERT INTO ...SELECT` it's telling you the problem; there is no table `[server2].[database2].[schema2].Table2`. Why are you also using 4 part naming for *both* object here? Are both objects on different servers and you are using a 3rd server as a "go between"? Why not run the query on `Server1` or `Server2`?

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, im not using 4 part for Table1, just a mistake while writing the question, I just corrected it. Yes I understand I cant use `Insert Into... Select` on remote server. 
What I need is to create a copy of Table1 in server2. If it was the same server I would use `INSERT INTO... SELECT` , but since it's not, what is the alternative?

Comment: Define your columns... YOu should be doing that anyway. Though `SELECT ... INTO` suggests the table `table2` doesn't exist on the destination server; if it *does* the `SELECT...INTO` wouldn't have worked regardless.

Comment: @Larnu I know Table2 doesnt exist on the destination server. I want to creat a copy of Table1. If I was doing that on the same server I could do `SELECT...INTO Table2` and could make a copy. How can I do that on a remote server? 
`CREATE` each column first, then `INSERT INTO`?

Comment: You need to `CREATE` the table on the remote server first, yes . Then you can use `INSERT INTO` (and define the columns you want too both in the `INSERT` and `SELECT` clauses).

Comment: @Larnu the issue is how can I dynamically create it. Because I'm the deleting it before using `EXEC [server2].[database2].sys.sp_executesql N'drop table if exists [schema2].Table2'`. Can I do `EXEC [server2].[database2].sys.sp_executesql N'Create Table database2.schema2.Table2
(
  column1 datatype,
  column2 datatype,
  column3 datatype
)'`?

Comment: Why do you "need" to dynamically create it? Get the definition of the table and `CREATE` it. Alternatively, connect to `Server2` and then you *can* use a `SELECT...INTO`.

Comment: @Larnu This queries are running inside a procedure. I need the table to be empty everytime I re-run it.

Comment: Then `TRUNCATE` it. `DROP TABLE` doesn't "empty" a table (`DELETE` all the data), it *drop*s it; it means the table doesn't exist any more. If you want the table to be empty, don't `DROP` it, `TRUNCATE` it, so that all the pages are deleted, but the table itself is not.